# logic and communication technicalities between computer components

Tags: computer-architecture

Concerning modern computers communicating with each other it is my understanding that computers are reading patterns in current flow and interpreting those patterns of current flow as ours 1's and 0's.I make the following assumptions here.Whether hard wired or wireless the communications start and end their journey as electrical signals within solid hardware.All human tech is powered by electricity which is simply the movement of electrons through a conductor. Electronics can't read atomic particles as they have no data that may be read by classic electronics.With it in mind that electricity can't be read by any classic tech and that all wires only carry electricity it suggest to me that electronics are recognizing and responding to patterns in the current flow to communicate. Ex. A pattern of .5 volts then .7 volts alternating at 4 second intervals might be interpreted as 1100010 while a pattern of .4 volts & .8 volts alternating at 8 second intervals would be interpreted as something else. It is because of this language of current flow patterns that we can use something like a scope to observe waveforms (voltage over time ) and interpret the waveforms to diagnose communication faults between modules on a can bus or other network for example.
Is this understanding on the technicals of computer communications between each other correct ? Complete ? Thanks Friends

Comment: `correct?` errm, [`volts`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt) is a unit for *electric potential difference*, not for current (ampere). There have been at least two [logic families](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family) with current inputs, but voltage/threshold inputs are more common. "Communication" sounds *more than one nanosecond apart*, which amounts to .2 meters/8 inches with earthly dielectrics. There, different techniques may apply than in "inter-logic-gate"/"intra-chip" signalling. The example looks *human interface* for the use of seconds instead of nanoseconds.

Comment: (While I don't think this is a CS question/context, it may help to disclose the context where this does come up.)

Comment: We discourage "is this correct?" questions.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that are likely to be useful to others in the future.  It's unlikely that anyone else will have exactly the same question.  Also, yes/no questions only have a yes/no answer, which is unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  It sounds like your question might be a better fit for individual tutoring than our site here.   Also, your question seems to be more about electronics and EE rather than CS.

Comment: If you can articulate a single, specific, focused question about CS, that'd be suitable here.